# Image downloaded from DownloadManager queuing on Android

Tags: android, image, file

I have this code that downloads an image but for some reason the image is in my downloads as "queued" instead of downloading.

```
        String url = file.public_url;

        getContext();
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

        request.setTitle(file.filename);
        request.setDescription(file.filename + " description.");
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true);
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, file.filename + file.file_extension);

        manager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: What if you remove the setAllowedNetworkTypes call?

Comment: @MateusGondim This does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully downloaded the images with this Async version that doesn't use DownloadManager https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028660/6136947